# Cant upgrade Xdebug?

Tags: php, php7, xdebug

1. I'm currently running the following PHP/Xdebug setup:

`PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.10.1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2019 14:54:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.10.1, ...
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans`

2. Reading up on Installing PHPUnit, [the docs](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.0/installation.html) state that --based on my installed version of PHP *(7.2.15)*  -- I need to install **PHPUnit 8.0**. And the code coverage report feature for PHPUnit 8.0 requires the **Xdebug (*2.7.0* or later)** and tokenizer extensions. Generating XML reports requires the xmlwriter extension.
3. But, I'm running **Xdebug v2.6.0**. So I ran `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug` to try to update Xdebug and saw this...

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
php-xdebug is already the newest version (2.6.0-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.`

So... I ***cant*** upgrade? ...now what?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps :

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt-cache policy php-xdebug
```

Then you can choose what version you want to install.

```
sudo apt install php-xdebug=2.7... (copy whole version number)
```

And to confirm the right version was installed `php -v`.

Anyway, if you encounter any issues, copy the output here and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: It helps, but it also installed the latest version of php. So, if someone follows this advice and don't need latest version of php - just remove it with command like `apt purge php8.2`